# How to Add/Insert Some Text to Body at Every New Page, As If It Was Input Directly

Tags: page, output-routine, atbegshi, everypage, shipout

Is there any way to add some text to **body** (not to header or footer) at every new page, as if it was input directly?

I want to do like following:

1. Input body text in normaly way;

```
This is line 1.
\par
This is line 2.
```

2. Declare some text to add. For example, “`[Inserted text]\`.”
3. Then, at every new page, TeX program treats body text as if it was like:

```
[Inserted text]\ 
This is line 1.
\par
This is line 2.
```

4. So that the output is like this:

```
((Indent))[Inserted text] This is line 1.((Line Break))
((Indent))This is line 2.
```

---

Here is what I did to achieve it. All trys resulted in failure.
(Please don't mind about the different widths of the images)

First, I tried defining `\@texttop` command;

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@texttop}{[Inserted text]\ }
\makeatother
```

The output was like this:

[image: defining <code>\@texttop</code> command]

Second, I tried using [atbegshi](https://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) package;

```
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout{%
\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{[Inserted text]\ }%
}
```

The output was like this:

[image: using atbegshi package]

Third, I tried patching in `\@outputpage` command:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\x@@outputpage@orig\@outputpage
\renewcommand{\@outputpage}{%
\let\x@@begindvi@orig\@begindvi
\renewcommand{\@begindvi}{%
\x@@begindvi@orig
\setbox\@outputbox\vbox{%
[Inserted text]\ 
\unvbox\@outputbox
}%
}%
\x@@outputpage@orig
}%
}%
\makeatother
```

The output was like this:

[image: patching in <code>\@outputpage</code> command]

But, what I want actually like this:

[image: what I want actually]

Is there any way to achieve it?

Here is a sample document:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{ifthen}

% 1. Define \@texttop Command
% \makeatletter
% \newcommand{\@texttop}{[Inserted text]\ }
% \makeatother

% 2. Use atbegshi Package
% \usepackage{atbegshi}
% \AtBeginShipout{%
% \AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{[Inserted text]\ }%
% }

% 3. Patch in \@outputpage Command
% \makeatletter
% \AtBeginDocument{%
% \let\x@@outputpage@orig\@outputpage
% \renewcommand{\@outputpage}{%
% \let\x@@begindvi@orig\@begindvi
% \renewcommand{\@begindvi}{%
% \x@@begindvi@orig
% \setbox\@outputbox\vbox{%
% [Inserted text]\ 
% \unvbox\@outputbox
% }%
% }%
% \x@@outputpage@orig
% }%
% }%
% \makeatother

\title{How to Add/Insert Some Text to Body at Every New Page, As If It Was Input Directly}
\author{\texttt{cmplstofB}}

\begin{document}
% What I Want Actually
% [Inserted text]\ 
\newcounter{tmpcntx}%
\setcounter{tmpcntx}{1}%
\whiledo{\value{tmpcntx}<90}{%
This is line \arabic{tmpcntx}.
\par
\stepcounter{tmpcntx}%
}%
\newpage
And, here is new page.
\newpage
[Inserted text]\ Acctually, I want a output like this.
\end{document}
```

Comment: well not with atbegshi and similar. You want to change the page *before* it is output not later. But I won't wander to some external site to download an example. Examples should be added here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see. I’ll add it.